# Mysterious Bug: React Native view is broken (but not crashing) after navigating to another React Native view and back

Tags: android, react-native

I'm adding few React Native views in existing native Android application.

When I'm showing one view it works fine. After I navigate to another view and go back the first view is not crashing, but is broken, that is: not clickable, carousel is scrollable, but behaves oddly (not snapping to particular component).

I see suspicious warnings in logs, but they are show not at the moment the view is shown back again, but later - at the moment of trying to touch/interact:

```
10-16 11:38:59.890 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached
10-16 11:38:59.891 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached
10-16 11:38:59.892 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Tried to enqueue runnable on already finished thread: 'js... dropping Runnable.
10-16 11:38:59.906 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/MessageQueue: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {edf0718} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {edf0718} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
        at android.os.Handler.enqueueMessage(Handler.java:643)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageAtTime(Handler.java:612)
        at android.os.Handler.sendMessageDelayed(Handler.java:582)
        at android.os.Handler.post(Handler.java:338)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl.runOnQueue(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:59)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext.runOnJSQueueThread(ReactContext.java:297)
        at com.facebook.react.uimanager.events.EventDispatcher$ScheduleDispatchFrameCallback.doFrame(EventDispatcher.java:285)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ReactChoreographer$ReactChoreographerDispatcher.doFrame(ReactChoreographer.java:134)
        at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ChoreographerCompat$FrameCallback$1.doFrame(ChoreographerCompat.java:105)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:925)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:635)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
10-16 11:38:59.907 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached
10-16 11:38:59.929 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached
10-16 11:38:59.940 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached
```

Views are implemented as Fragments with react-native-android-fragment (v1.0.0)

Anyone had similar issue? Any suggestions on how to trace this down?

Comment: Posting the code would help figuring out what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it seems to be an issue with react-native-android-fragment and it's usage.

Scenario:

1. Create two ReactFragments, A and B, on a tab view for example
2. A is visible (resumed), B is hidden (paused)
3. Hide fragment A, show B
4. Destroy fragment B, onDestroy clears the ReactNativeHost (reactInstanceMgr.getLifecycleState() returns BEFORE_RESUME):
5. Show A back again, try to interact with it

This results with a warnings:

```
10-16 11:38:59.891 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Unable to dispatch touch to JS as the catalyst instance has not been attached
10-16 11:38:59.892 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/unknown:ReactNative: Tried to enqueue runnable on already finished thread: 'js... dropping Runnable.
10-16 11:38:59.906 9618-9618/com.someapp.android W/MessageQueue: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {edf0718} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Handler (com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler) {edf0718} sending message to a Handler on a dead thread
        at android.os.MessageQueue.enqueueMessage(MessageQueue.java:543)
...
```

Posted issue here: https://github.com/hudl/react-native-android-fragment/issues/18